# Convert List to DataFrame and Split nested dictionary inside DataFrame column - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I want to convert List to DataFrame and Split nested dictionary inside DataFrame column, below is my code.

```
import pandas

d = [{"key":1000000, "name":"Aelf", "level":0, "hasData":"true", "fields":{"id":"elf"}}]
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to split "fields" into new column "id"

```
key name    level   hasData fields  id
1000000 Aelf    0   true    {'id': 'elf'}   elf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` with `pop` + `tolist`:

```
d = [{"key":1000000, "name":"Aelf", "level":0, "hasData":"true", "fields":{"id":"elf"}},
     {"key":2000000, "name":"Cdaf", "level":1, "hasData":"false", "fields":{"id":"deer"}}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

res = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('fields').tolist()))
```

Result:

```
  hasData      key  level  name    id
0    true  1000000      0  Aelf   elf
1   false  2000000      1  Cdaf  deer
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `concat`

```
pd.concat([df,df.fields.apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
Out[308]: 
          fields hasData      key  level  name   id
0  {'id': 'elf'}    true  1000000      0  Aelf  elf
```